# First screen in navigation stack in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is it possible to check the number of screens in the react-navigation stack? I need to display the logo component in the header only for the first screen in the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You can use

```
let index = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state.index;
```

To get the index in the stack. If the index is 0 then you are at the first screen on the stack.

You can read more about it [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#dangerouslygetparent-get-parent-navigator). Your use case is exactly what this is for:

> Another good use case for this is to find the index of the active
>   route in the parent's route list. So in the case of a stack if you are
>   at index 0 then you may not want to render a back button, but if
>   you're somewhere else in the list then you would render a back button.

**Just remember to make sure that the call returns a valid value.**

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, @Andrew mant thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

The Andrew solution works fine for you, but those who want to get the updated state you have to use useNavigationState, accordingly to the navigation docs:

> The navigation.dangerouslyGetState() function also returns the current navigation state. The main difference is that the useNavigationState hook will trigger a re-render when values change, while navigation.dangerouslyGetState() won't.

just use like this:

```
const index = useNavigationState(state => state.index);
```